# What's the name of print samples collected by photographers?

Tags: portfolio, publishing

When a photographer's work is used in a magazine, pamphlet, etc., it's natural that the photographer would want a copy to show as part of his portfolio.

I'm positive I've seen a name for this -- cut sheet, maybe -- but I'm getting goose-eggs on google.  This should be an easy one for someone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a tear sheet.  Newspapers can usually supply this a a vector PDF but when my photo was published in a magazine, i only received the actual tear sheets and no digital files.